# How to compute the theoretical power spectrum of a first order autoregression (AR1) model

Tags: power-spectral-density, autoregressive-model

I'm trying to figure out how to compute the **theoretical** power spectrum of a **first-order autoregression model (AR1)**.

The AR1 model is given as

$x_i = r_1 x_{i-1} + e_i$

where:

- $x_i$ is real-valued number at index $i$,
- $e_i$ is random Gaussian noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$,
- $r_1$ is the lag-1 autoregession parameter in range $[-1, 1]$.

The sequence $x_i$ is assumed to be stationary with $0$ mean.

I've found 2 different equations for computing the theoretical power spectrum for an AR1 model:

1. From Wilks 2019, Statistical Methods in the Atmospheric Sciences Fourth Edition, Chapter 10:

$S(f) = \frac{4 \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 / n}{1 + \phi^2 - 2\phi \cos(2\pi f)}$, $0\le f \le 1/2$

where:

- $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ is the variance of random noise.
- $n$ the length of the sequence.
- $f$ the frequency.
- $\phi$ the autoregression parameter.

2. From Torrence, Christopher and Compo, Gilbert P., 1998: A Practical Guide to Wavelet Analysis. Bulletin of the American Meteorological Society, 1, 61-78:

$S(k) = \frac{1 - \phi^2}{1 + \phi^2 - 2\phi \cos(2\pi k/n)}$, $k=0, 1, 2, \cdots, n/2$

**NOTE that** It was stated that this was after normalization by multiplying $n / \sigma_x^2$.

Given $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2 = (1 - \phi^2) \sigma_{x}^2$, I can see that the method-1 is 4 times that of the method-2.

However, when I tried to simulate this using the following python script, it seems that the averaged PSD from simulations is 2 times that of the method-2.

So did I get anything wrong in my code, and what's the correct formula?

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def genAR1(r1, var_error, length):
    '''Generate a random AR1 sequence given lag-1 autocorrelation

    r1: lag-1 autocorrelation
    var_error: variance of random noise
    length: length of the sequence
    '''

    errors = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(var_error), size=length)
    res = [0, ]

    for i in range(1, length):
        res.append(res[i-1]*r1 + errors[i])

    return np.array(res)

def PSD(y):
    '''Compute power spectrum for 1d array using Fourier transform '''

    # Remove mean
    yp = y - np.mean(y)
    n = len(y)

    # Do FFT
    cf = np.fft.fft(yp)/n
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n)

    # Get power
    p = np.abs(cf)**2

    # take only the non-negative freqs but scale power by 2
    idx = np.where(freq >= 0)[0]
    freq = freq[idx]
    p = 2. * np.take(p, idx)

    return p, freq

def PSDofAR1(r1, var_e, n, freqs):
    '''Get theoretical PSD of AR1

    r1: lag-1 autocorrelation
    var_e: variance of random noise
    n: length of the sequence
    freqs: frequencies from 0 to 0.5
    '''

    num = 4 * var_e / n
    den = 1 + r1**2 - 2 * r1 * np.cos(2*np.pi*freqs)
    return num/den

r1 = 0.7
var_error = 1.

ps_list = []
# repeat 1000 times
for i in range(1000):

    rand_ts = genAR1(r1, var_error, length=500)
    ps, freq = PSD(rand_ts)
    ps_list.append(ps)

# mean power spectrum of AR1 sequences
ps_mean = np.mean(ps_list, axis=0)

# theoretical ps
theo_ps = PSDofAR1(r1, var_error, 500, freq)

#-------------------Plot------------------------
figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(freq, ps_mean, 'b-', label='Mean PSD')
ax.plot(freq, theo_ps, 'r-', label='Theoretical PSD method-1')
ax.legend()
figure.show()
```

Output image:
[image]

Comment: Does it have something to do with the treatment of negative frequencies?

Comment: @EdV Thanks. Now I tend to believe that the method-1 equation from Wilks is wrong, and my simulation appears to be twice as large as method-2 is due to me adding the negative frequencies.

Comment: @EdV. Thanks, I corrected the n/2 typo. The omega = 0 value looks fine if I do not remove the mean before doing the FFT.

Comment: @Jason: If you google for "power spectrum of an AR(1)", there is a result ( it's first for me )  titled "spectral density". These are slides by a professor at berkeley. Page 12 has yet another result that is similar to both of yours but not the same. In addition to negative frequencies, it may have something to do with the way covariance is defined in DSP versus the way it is defined in statistics. These slides define it the way it's defined in statistics because the slides are from a statistics department. The derivation is given step by step so hopefully it's useful to you.